# Extracting String in Regex in Flutter and Converting it To Int

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Flutter bit of code here, which is a large String. It would be different every time, but the format would stay the same since it's a template:

```
 "William\nWilliam description here...\n$^170^ usd" + Uuid().v4()
```

I want to extract the **170** part, and then convert it to interger, so I can remove it from list of ints. I have tried a lot of code, but it isn't working for a few reasons, one is I can't extract the actual number from the String between the **^** and **^**, and then I can't convert it to interger. Here's the try function (incomplete).

```
deleteSumItem(item) {
final regEx = RegExp(r'\^\d+(?:\^\d+)?'); //not sure if this is right regex for the String template
final priceValueMatch = regEx.firstMatch(item); //this doesn't return the particular number extracted
_totalPrice.remove(priceValueMatch); //i get error here that it isn't a int
_counter = _counter - priceValueMatch; //then remove it from interger as int
}
```

The function would take that String (**"William\nWilliam description here...\n$^170^ usd" + Uuid().v4()**) template (the number would be different between the ^ ^, but the template is same), then convert it to interger and remove from list as int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
void main() {
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'\^(\d+)\^');
  String input = r"William\nWilliam description here...\n$^170^ usd";
  
  String match = regExp.firstMatch(input).group(1);
  print(match); // 170
  
  int number = int.parse(match);
  print(number); // 170
}
```

I have changed the RegExp so it does correctly capture the number in its own capture group. It looked like you got a little confused in the process of creating the RegExp but it could also be I am missing some details about the problem.

Comment: Yeah I might have gotten a bit confused, have been working on a project with thousands of lines, so this could help me out. Let me try it out and I'll get back to you asap. Thank you!

Comment: I got it to work, I updated the code in main post, just in case someone else has a similar issue. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @arbiter `"r" + '"' + input + '"'` does not make any sense. `r` for raw strings is only used for Strings in your code to indicate to the compiler the written string should be parsed as raw. If the string are already loaded in the system, it does not matter if the string are "raw".